# Get MySQL ID while inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the row ID after the slug (ex. post 1 returns "/bligpost.php?id=1").
Instead, it returns no ID.
Where am I doing it wrong? (I have included my other attempts in comments.)

```
mysql_connect("$hosty","$uname","$paswd");
@mysql_select_db($dbnme) or die( "Unable to select database");

$name=$_POST['Title'];
$slug="blogpost.php?id=";
$auth=$_POST['Author'];
$date=$_POST['Date'];
$cont=$_POST['Content'];

//$query = ("INSERT INTO Blogs (Name, URL, Content, Author, Date) VALUES ('$name', '$slug', '$cont', '$auth', '$date')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Blogs (id, Name, URL, Content, Author, Date) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$slug', '$cont', '$auth', '$date')");
//$pind = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL=blogpost.php?id=`id` WHIERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()");
//mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL=blogpost.php?id=".$pind." WHERE Content=".$cont);
mysql_close();
```

Comment: just a note: `mysql_ functions() are deprecated and are going to be removed in newer versions. Use PDO or Mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're actually doing wrong in the commented line when assigning to `$pind` is you expect the `mysql_query` to return your new id, but what it actually returns is a resource from which you must get the id using `mysql_fetch_row` or any similar function from the `mysql_fetch_` family.

As for the uncommented row with `WHIERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()`, it would probably work, but you're not concatenating the prefix string with your id. You should do it like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE blogs SET url = CONCAT('blogpost.php?id=', id) WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

On the other hand I don't approve of your design of holding your urls in the database when you already have everything you need in the database (i.e. the id), so you should just prepend the "blogpost.php?id=" to the id you get when selecting that row and you're all set, this url of yours is completely unnecessary.

Oh and people are correct when they say this is deprecated, but it seems you're still learning so this is probably a little easier to grasp than the mysqli approach so you can stick with it for now and move up to mysqli once you're comfortable.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: The "blogpost?id=" part is solely for the laziness, actually. ;) But CONCAT was the one I needed, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by laziness. You're either concatenating in SQL  or in PHP. In PHP it's either just a dot, in SQL it's CONCAT. :) Actually in PHP/HTML template it would just be <a href="blogpost.php?id=<?=$id?>">, so it's even easier and you can change your mind about the blogpost.php part easier. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with  **mysql_insert_id**() like

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Blogs (id, Name, URL, Content, Author, Date) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$slug', '$cont', '$auth', '$date')");
$id =  mysql_insert_id();
echo "My Last Inserted Id ".$id;
```

Tr this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) And dont use mysql_* functions due to they are depricated,instead of it,use mysqli_* or PDO statements

And try to update your update query like

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL = 'blogpost.php?id=$id' WHERE id=$id");
```

**EDIT** Based on your commented query try like

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL=blogpost.php?id=$pind WHERE Content='".$cont."'")
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL=blogpost.php?id=$pind WHERE Content='$cont'")
```

Comment: The ID returns on the page correctly, but it still doesn't add it after the slug. "$slug="blogpost.php?id=".$pind;"

Comment: No, still not. "mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL=blogpost.php?id=".$pind." WHERE Content=".$cont);"

Comment: You need to clean up the update statement I think. - *mysql_query("UPDATE Blogs SET URL='blogpost.php?id=$id' WHERE id=$id");*

Comment: I saw your edit afterwards (you're so fast!). But it didn't solve it yet. (Damn enters!)

Comment: Tried, but still no id after the slug.

Comment: For example, if the id is 15, the slug should look like "/blogpost.php?id=15". "/blogpost.php?id=" is my slug (accessed by the URL), 15 is my id. All I want to do, is add the 15 after the "?id=" part in PHP and then pass it to the MySQL column.

Comment: Then before update statement give like $my_string ="/blogpost.php?id".$id; and in update query UPDATE Blogs SET URL='$my_string'...

Comment: Or put the quotes around the string within the update statement

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
   $pind = mysql_insert_id();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

$id = mysql_insert_id();

In table id field should be auto increment field